# Can we compare time in while loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server

is it possible if I want to compare between time in WHILE condition? Something like below.

```
WHILE (convert(varchar,convert(time,@DisplayStartTime),100) between convert(varchar,convert(time,@DisplayStartTime),100)  and ltrim(right(convert(varchar(100), DATEADD(minute, 960, @DisplayStartTime)),8)))
BEGIN
    SET @DisplayStartTime = @nextStartTime

    SELECT @nextStartTime = ltrim(right(convert(nvarchar(100), DATEADD(minute, @Frequency, @nextStartTime)), 8))

    INSERT INTO #ActualTimeSlot
        SELECT @Parameter, @DisplayStartTime, 
               @nextStartTime, @CodeEndTime, @Frequency, @Tolerance 


    SET @intFlag +=1
END
```

Thanks in advance.

I expected it to return something like that. However, it keep only return until the row 5 which is not right.

[image]

Comment: can we have some sample data and what output you want out of your query ?

Comment: yes, that is my expected output.

Comment: Isn't it the same question as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31041949/how-can-compare-between-times-in-while-loop-in-stored-procedure)?

Comment: yes it is.but i think my previous question is a bit confusing.i'm sorry.

Comment: Can you convert DATEADD(minute, 960, @DisplayStartTime)),8) this into time and check

Comment: alright let me try that